# The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I am developing a Metro style app using C# and xaml.

In my application I got the error when calling to a web service:

> The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.

What is the reason for this error?

Answer (score 2):

I have a crawler program and a few moments ago I got  the same exception. The reason in my case is that the security certificate (of the site I have been crawling)  expired.

A quick fix in my case was adding this line of code:

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new
RemoteCertificateValidationCallback
(
   delegate { return true; }
);
```

Note: this hack could be a security threat